# Average sample size of two fishers z correlations

Tags: variance, standard-error, meta-analysis, pearson-r, fisher-transform

I am conducting a meta analysis of Pearson's r correlations. As there are two  correlations , sometimes three , for the same study and dependent variable I have averaged the correlations via fishers z transformations. I now need one sample size for both correlations in order to calculate the standard error of the combined average score. If I am to use the formula of 1/(√N−3)to calculate the standard error of the averaged score then this requires one sample size. 
Is there a way in which to calculate a combined or averaged sample size please?

Answer (score 1):

If you have $k$ values of $z_i$ each based on $N_i$ as its, possibly differetn sample size then the average $z$ is

$$
z_{av} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^k (N_i - 3) * z_i}{\sum_{i=1}^k (N_i - 3)}
$$

and the standard error of $z_{av}$ is

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sum{(N_i - 3)}}}
$$

Comment: Thanks, I have just been provided with a formula of N - 3k. Is that a suitable formula too?

Comment: What does $N$ mean in that formula?

Comment: sorry ,  sum of sample sizes. K is number of samples

Comment: Simple algebra shows that to be equivalent to the more general formula.